# What if YouTube owner doesn't respond if I can use their upload further?

Tags: youtube

I was looking for a video for knowledge and blogpost which I found on YouTube under Standard YouTube License. However, when I tried to contact the owner, I think he/she is not active on YouTube anymore. Because that is the last video uploaded by the user and that is 7 years ago. What to do?

Comment: What is it you planned to do with the video?  A link to it is probably fine.  Embedding it on your site or in your blog is probably allowed under the YouTube Standard License as well, but there may be requirements (like you have to show who created & uploaded the video). Question: Could you find another video with the same information?  If so, perhaps the owner of that video may respond to you.

Comment: I'm planning to embed the video on my blog not just the link. It's a 1958 documentary which I think owner didn't create himself/herself. For your reference this is the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJ6w1esVcoY

Comment: I just Googled "youtube standard license embedding". It looks as though you can do that without any issues.  [Here is the link.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/6j6AkVVJbvs) But that YouTube uploaded someone else's material, which may mean that the video will be removed from his/her channel. Therefore, check your blog periodically to make sure your embedded video will still play.

Comment: Thank you buddy.. Finally I have completed my blogpost. if you wish you can check it here. And yes, feedbacks are welcome! :-)
http://www.nirmitkapoor.com/single-post/Return-of-Analog-or-Film-Photography

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, really. YouTube Standard License doesn't give you any rights to redistribute or remix the video (see [my answer here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/is-one-able-to-override-the-terms-of-the-youtube-standard-licence-with-a-sligh/20236#20236)). You can only try to contact the uploader through other means. Look through their channel info to see if you can find a website, Twitter, E-Mail address or any other contact information. Depending on how badly you want to use this video, there are also other means of <strike>online stalking</strike> finding contact information that you might try. For example, if he uses a distinct user name you can try to search for that user name on Google, Twitter or other social media and see if you find something.

Comment: Hey Moritz, Thanks a lot for the swift reply. As you said, I tried to get any available contact info for the user but it seems that either user is no longer using the account or account is not accessible to the user. Google+ profile only shows 1 follower and not even a single reply on the comments below the video in last 7 years. Though I have left a comment to reply me back by February 3rd else I will consider it as yes with an apology. Is it okay to go ahead after February 3rd?

Comment: @NKAPOOR If by *go ahead* you mean use his video for whatever you are working on, no. A videomaker owns his content, so he gets to set the rules on how to use it. If he doesn't want anyone to use his video, that's his decision. He also is not obliged to answer you (even if the answer is no), and you don't get to set a deadline after which his content is fair game. Copyright is implicit in most countries, meaning if you create something, you hold the copyright to it by default. In Germany for example, the copyright only expires 70 year's after the artists death ...

Comment: I agree @Moritz and I respect the ownership of the content anyone creates. Being a Photographer, I'm very well aware of the copyrights. As a matter of fact, this is a 1958 documentary for film rolls which I think uploader didn't create. Here is the link for your reference, do read the description of the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJ6w1esVcoY

Comment: @NKAPOOR I see. In that case, there's no use in contacting the uploader anyway, as I find it very unlikely the he holds the copyright and if he doesn't, he can't give out any rights he doesn't have. If you want to use this film in any project of yours, you will have to find out who holds the copyright and inquire with them about the usage, which might prove quite difficult. What do you mean with 'use in your blogpost'? If you only want to showcase it, can't you just embed or link to the video? Legally it's still a grey area, but everyone does it and no one really cares to sue over that ...

Comment: If you live in the USA, depending on what you want to do with the video (e.g. if you want to review it or use it for educational purposes), your usage might fall under [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use), in which case you don't need to ask permission at all. However this depends heavily on how you use the video. I'm also not a lawyer, so don't consider any of this legal advice by the way

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. I really appreciate your views on this. As I said I do not want people to go here and there for all the links and videos. I try to make my own content and share it on blogpost so that reader is not jumping from one link to another. It should be one stop shop for the audience. However, this is something I can't create on my own as you know film photography is struggling to survive. I'm actually writing a blog on the recent announcement of Kodak to bring film rolls back so I wanted to share my views on efforts of making a film roll. I hope it make sense.

Comment: @NKAPOOR Well, I read in your other comment that you only intend to embed the video in your blog, to be honest I think you can just go ahead and do that. The thing is, people 'steal' content on the internet all the time and no one comes after them. Visit reddit at any given time and you will find tons of stuff that has been taken from some other place without giving credit. And what you are doing isn't even that, since embedding the video means your readers can still see the original uploader. There is no law against embedding videos, and no precedent case. TBC ...

Comment: This may not stay this way forever. A while back, someone in Germany has been fined for sharing a picture on Facebook, so I dare say this might eventually become more of an issue. However, in your case I don't think you have much to worry about. For once, the video you want to use is very old. The copyright is probably part of the portfolio of some large company that won't be bothered to sue anyone over uploading it to Youtube or embedding it in their blog. I dare say the uploader on YouTube didn't hold the rights either ...

Comment: Thank you buddy.. Finally I have completed my blogpost. if you wish you can check it here. And yes, feedbacks are welcome! :-)
http://www.nirmitkapoor.com/single-post/Return-of-Analog-or-Film-Photography